# Do I need to create fragments in this kind of condition?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, openweathermap

I am confused whether I need to create a fragment in this situation or not. On main activity, I have a EditText field for taking city name as user input and  a button below clicking which should display weather information from openweathermap.com's API current temperature, Wind Speed and Weather description along with a button that displays Latitude and Longitude on the same screen. Below the Submit city button. Clicking the button on latitude and longitude should display google map for that place along with markers displaying temperature.

Do I need to create fragment in this case? I think so but I am not sure. I am not able to start to code.

How if i create EditText for city input and submit button on activity and create the 3 text fields for weather and button displaying latitude and longitude on a fragment and another fragment to display map? Am i thinking the right way?

Could you help me with your knowledge?

Comment: It depends on how you are planning to grow your app. If i am going to open a screen from multiple places(sources) i usually make that screen an activity so i can manage it easier. If the screen will be opened from a single source i usually make that a fragment

Comment: @hrskrs At first only EditText for city and submit should be displayed. The 3 textView and button should appear on the screen only after submitting the city name. Is it possible to do only with main Activity?

Comment: You can do it by playing with their `visibility`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on whether you want to support for tablets or not?

If not then you don't need fragments since all the view groups are stacked vertically.

Comment: At first only EditText for city and submit should be displayed. The 3 textView and button should appear on the screen only after submitting the city name. Is it possible to do only with main Activity?

Comment: Yes, by using `setVisibility`. Set this method to Visible when you want to show The 3 text views and map. No need for fragments.

Comment: Do you know any youtube link showing that thing that matches my condition more or less using setVisibility?

Comment: Quick search gave me this video, I haven't verified the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UBJxRrn2xu0

Comment: It is not a complex topic. Simply try `textView.setVisibility(View.Visible);` in your code when you want to display the text view. Before that in the XML, for the text view, add `android:visibility="gone"`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your MainActivity and you don't need fragment.When you will press submit button you may restart your activity if necessary.Using fragment in this case is not really necessary but if you want you may use fragment as well.